# How to make a []array & map with contains []array

Tags: json, api, go, controller, beego

How to make a map like `"Data":[{"3":{...}},{"4":{...}}]`

Controller

```
jsons := make(map[string]interface{})
listUsers := identity.ListUsers()
users := make(map[int]interface{})

for k, j := range listUsers {
        if j.Description != "" {
            users[k] = j
    }
}

jsons["Data"] = users
u.Data["json"] = jsons
u.ServeJSON()
```

JSON

```
 "Data": {
    "3": {
        "default_project_id": "",
        "description": "description",
        "domain_id": "default",
        "enabled": true
    },
    "5": {
        "default_project_id": "9e266e1a750e45f8862e83341a5d0970",
        "description": "description",
        "domain_id": "default",
        "enabled": true
    }
}
```

[image: please help me with this error]

> listUsers []users.User
>   users map[int]interface{}

I just gotta add more details, when I get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,`"Data":[ "3":{...},"4":{...} ]` is not a valid format of json.You can't put key-value data inside `[]` except `{}`.So something inside `[]` must be list.So you can change it like `"Data":[{"3":{...}},{"4":{...}}]`.

Then change the controller code like `users := make([]map[int]interface{},0)`

Comment: `cannot use j (type users.User) as type []map[int]interface {} in assignment`

Comment: @М.Билгүүн change users assignment to `users = append(users, map[int]interface{}{k: j,})`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create new types:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
DefaultProjectID string `json:"default_project_id"`
Description      string `json:"description"`
DomainID         string `json:"domain_id"`
Enabled          bool   `json:"enabled"`
```

}

type MyType map[int]AutoGenerated

I think that is not a good idea to create a slice of map but can:

```
type SliceMap []MyType
```

To generate new go-types from JSON you can use: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/